# How to show Next & Previous page links in Django-CMS

Tags: django-cms

We've a site built in Django-CMS and have developed a mobile version with alternative CSS to suit the smaller viewing area. As well as the usual navigation bar we want to include Next and Previous page links at the bottom of each page.

I know how to output the current page's siblings using this code:

```
{% show_menu current_page.level %}
```

What is the easiest way to output links to the next and previous page?

Comment: Presumably?  Yes.  You can always presume such a thing.  Not a really great question.   "Is it a good way to use the Django framework?" is a better question.  "What kind of code would be used for this?" would be an even better question.  Perhaps you might want to update your question to identify **specifically** what you want to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `{{ request.current_page.get_next_sibling }}` and `{{ request.current_page.get_previous_sibling }}` in your templates to show the 'neighbor' pages (not that either or b

Comment: That works well, I've used {% page_url %} to get the URL, like this: <a href="{% page_url current_page.get_previous_sibling %}">&laquo; Previous</a>

Comment: How to limit only to get next/prev published page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the methods `get_next_filtered_sibling` and `get_previous_filtered_sibling` - but probably only for newer versions of the django cms.

Here are two template tags that return page objects which you might want to feed into the `{% page_url ... %}` template tag.

```
@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_next_page(context):
    current_page = context['request'].current_page
    return current_page.get_next_filtered_sibling(
        publisher_is_draft=False
    )

@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_prev_page(context):
    current_page = context['request'].current_page
    return current_page.get_previous_filtered_sibling(
        publisher_is_draft=False
    )
```